# Unable to draw to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a project where I have to create a block breaking game in canvas, but for some reason the code has stopped drawing in the canvas and I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem.

```js
//global variable

//setting the canvas state
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Boolean variables for each stage of the game
var startscreen = true;
var gameplaying = false;
var Game_over = false;

//Setting the ball position and size
var ball_x = canvas.width / 2;
var ball_y = canvas.height - 30;
var ballRadius = 5;

//Setting the ball movement
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;

//PLayer paddle size
var p_height = 10;
var p_width = 100;

//Player paddle start position
var Paddlex = (canvas.width - p_width) / 2;
var Paddley = canvas.height - p_height;

//making sure the paddle doesnt move on its own
var paddleright = false;
var paddleleft = false;

//Set up the target blocks
var brickRowCount = 5;
var brickColumnCount = 13;
var brickWidth = 24;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
var rowColours = ["#2294B2", "#FF3175", "#17CEFF", "#CCBF27", "#B2A507"];

var bricks = [];
for (c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for (r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      status: 1
    };
  }
}

//setting the event listeners to detect keypresses
document.addEventListener("Keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("Keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

//Detecting the key press
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    paddleright = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    paddleleft = true;
  }
}

//Detecting the Key press has stopped
function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    paddleright = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    paddleleft = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    startscreen = false;
    gameplaying = true;
    Game_over = false;
  }
}

//drawing the ball
function ball() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball_x, ball_y, ballRadius, 0, Math.pi * 2);
  ctx.fillstyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

//drawing player paddle
function paddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(Paddlex, Paddley, p_width, p_height);
  ctx.fillstyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

//Drawing the blocks
function drawBricks() {
  for (c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      ctx.fillstyle = rowColours[r];
      if (bricks[c][r].status === 1) {
        var brickX = (c * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (r * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}


//drawing the above functions to the screen
function draw() {
  //Startscreen and main menu
  if (startscreen) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //Set background colour
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 170, 0);
    gradient.addcolorstop(0, 'blue');
    gradient.addcolorstop(0, 'orange');

    ctx.fillstyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    //Welcome title
    ctx.font = '20px verdana';
    ctx.fillstyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText("Block Breaker", 50, 50);

    //Welcome tagline
    ctx.fillText("Break some blocks", 50, 100);

    //Rules of play text
    ctx.fillText("How to play:", 80, 200);
    ctx.fillText("To play, move the paddle", 80, 280);
    ctx.fillText("with the left and right arrow keys", 80, 310);
    ctx.fillText("Press ENTER to begin.", 80, 250);

    // Call key up function
    keyUpHandler();

  }

  //Game play 
  if (gameplaying) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //calling the ball, paddle and blocks in the draw function
    ball();
    paddle();
    drawBricks();

    //bounce off the walls
    if (ball_x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || ball_x + dx < ballRadius) {
      console.log("Ball bounced off the side");
      sx = -dx;
    }

    //if the ball hits the top
    if (ball_y + dy < ballRadius) {
      console.log("Ball bounced off the top");
    }

    //If the ball hits the bottom
    if (ball_y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {

      //If the ball hits the player1 paddle
      if (ball_y + dy > Paddley && ball_x > Paddlex && ball_x < Paddlex + p_width) {
        console.log("Ball hit the player paddle");
        dy = -dy;
      }

      //the ball hits the base
      else if (ball_y + dy > canvas.height) {
        console.log("Ball hit the bottom of the screen");
        gameplaying = false;
        Game_over = true;

      }
    }
  }

  //Gameover screen
  if (Game_over) {
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 170);
    gradient.addcolorstop(0, "blue");
    gradient.addcolorstop(0, "orange");
    ctx.fillstyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    //Welcome title
    ctx.font = '20px verdana';
    ctx.fillstyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText("Game Over", 50, 50);

    //Main Text body 
    ctx.fillText("Press Enter to return tot the main menu", 80, 200);

    //Reload the game
    function keyUpHandler(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        startscreen = true;
        Game_over = false;
      }
    }
  }

  //If the ball hits a block
  if (ball_x)


  //Movement speed of the paddle
    if (paddleright && Paddlex < canvas.width - p_width) {
    Paddlex += 5;
  } else if (paddleleft && Paddlex > 0) {
    Paddlex -= 5;
  }

  ball_x += dx;
  ball_y += dy;




  //Setting the framerate 
  setInterval(draw, 10);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: it's important to note when it went from working to not working. Your error will most likely be there. Also posting your HTML may help.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? (hit F12) You say it stopped drawing to the canvas. What did you change between when it was drawing and when it stopped drawing?

Comment: i'm not too sure at what point it stopped drawing tbh., also no problems show up in console debugger.

Comment: You have `setInterval` inside the function you set the interval callback to. That will quickly lead to a crash. Use `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout` never use `setInterval`. Also there is a conditional statement near the bottom that does not look right `if(ball_x)` the syntax is correct but the logic is not as that will be true while `ball_x !== 0 ` and you have the comment above it "//If the ball hits a block"

Comment: Basically, you aren't calling any of the functions you've defined. Once you do, you'll find mountains of errors. Have fun!

Comment: Their isn't much HTML in project just the draw canvas code.  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">

Answer (score 0):

move the following line down two lines (so it is not inside draw())

```
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Also, I would strongly encourage you to change 10 to (1000 / FPS), where FPS is frames per second.  You probably won't be able to finish executing draw() within 10ms thus creating a drag on the CPU